# What's the difference/relationship between history and places in GWT?

Tags: ajax, gwt

Based on my observation, the History is used in a single html page with multiple AJAX interactions. It just assigns each state to a specific token to distinguish(or mark) them. While for the Places, it's used for different html pages. It assigns each html page to a string token.

Is there any relationship between them? And do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html):

> A place is a Java object representing a particular state of the UI. A Place can be converted to and from a URL history token (see GWT’s History mechanism) by defining a PlaceTokenizer for each Place, and GWT’s PlaceHistoryHandler automatically updates the browser URL corresponding to each Place in your app.

So you can think of Places and Activities a higher level above History. For example, you can go to a new "place" in your application by changing the history token with `History.newItem("token")`. But you can use `PlaceController` to do the same: `placeController.goTo(new TokenPlace())`. `TokenPlace` is explicitly associated with the history token `token`, has an `Activity` class instantiated when this place is reached, etc. Under the hoods, `History.newItem("token")` will still be called, but you don't have to worry about managing history tokens manually. As a bonus, your application will probably become less coupled, because now `Activity1` doesn't have to know anything about `Activity2` - `Activity1` just triggers a move to a new Place. It doesn't care which activity it's associated with.

Comment: Hi, @Igor Klimer , wow, excellent answer! Thanks a lot! 
BTW, I think even with history, activity1 also doesn't need to know activity2, since the transmission is defined in the History.addValueChangeHandler (onValueChange). So, if we have a "manager" class which holds the references for all the activities, we can easily define their transmission there. So, in Activity1, if it wants to go to Activity2, it just need to invoke the History.newItem("Token_for_Activity2"), that's it. It only does not need to know Activity2.

Comment: You're right, "raw" History management also gives you decoupling. But why bother writing your own history manager, when you have the exact mechanism provided for you with Activties and Places? It's highly customizable too.