# How can my GWT webapp notice a new anchor being added to its URL

Tags: gwt, anchor

I want my GWT webapp to support deep links, so, if anybody clicks on a such a deep link my GWT webapp is pulled up and a certain document is shown which is referenced from within the deep link's url.

However, in case the webapp already exists in a browser tab this tab should be reused without actually reloading the webapp.

So, my thinking is to add an anchor to the url of the webapp's browser tab which includes the id of the document to show:
`Window.open("http://my-gwt-webapp.org/#some_document_id", "my_gwt_web_app", null);`

Adding the anchor to the url seems to work like a charm, except, the webapp has no clue what is happening and is therefore unable to react.

How can the webapp be made aware of the modified url?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [History mechanism](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html). Use `History.addValueChangeHandler` to listen to changes to the token (the part after `#`).

You can go step further and use [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html). You can read how those two relate to each other [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28201843/181497).

Comment: Excellent. Works great. It is possible to add any anchor to the url and the GWT History's value change handler will catch this and make the webapp react in any way desired. Thanks!